# Update a column based on record numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, row-number

I'm creating a column called "Deciles".  I need each decile to populate based on the range of the row numbers.  So 'Decile 1' would be between rows 1 and 364000.  The syntax I've used latest has not worked.  Please keep in mind I am not a programmer.  (SQL Server 2008 is the environment I'm using).  HELP!!

```
update dbo.August_Deciles
set Deciles = 'Decile 1'
Row_Number() over (Order By Row_Number())
between Row_Number(1) and  Row_Number(326424)
```

Comment: So for the second row it should be `Decile 2`?

Comment: No, Decile 2 will be for rows (326425 - 652850)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Deciles,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Deciles ASC)
    FROM dbo.August_Deciles
)
UPDATE CTE SET Deciles = 'Decile ' + CAST(RN as int)
```

You should replace `ORDER BY Deciles ASC` with a meaningful order.